# Printing shorts from a file in C

Tags: c, printf

Hey guys I am learning C and I searched this online however couldnt find any help. I am trying to read the bytes from a file, save them into a buffer, and then print them as shorts. But the code I have so far has some problems even though it looks logical to me. I would appreciate the help:

```
//print shorts

// write bits into the buffer 
int buffer[1600];
fread(buffer, 1, 1600, myfile);


//take them out as shorts from the buffer
int shrtcnt = 0; // short count
while (shrtcnt < 160){
    int nxtshrtcnt = shrtcnt + 16;
    printf("This is a short: ");
    for (int a = shrtcnt; a < nxtshrtcnt; a++){
        printf("%d", buffer[a]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    shrtcnt += 16;
}
```

This prints out some numbers but they are no where near to what i was expected them to be. Any ideas? 
I created a file and put the values in myself. The values I should get are 1112131415161718 i get values like  "192153000655350-20330470760655350-16777216-655360-655360000" honestly it looks like random to me.

Comment: I don't see any mention of the short type in your code, typo maybe ?

Comment: Show the input file, what you would like to be printed, and the actual output you are getting.

Comment: You don't read `short` and neither do you print `short` values. For the printing part I recommend [this `printf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: Why are you reading elements each size `1` into an `int` array?

Comment: That you are printing 16 values at a time suggests you think you have a bit array.

Comment: I thought shorts were 2 byte values? Thats why I am reading 16 bits

Comment: with what you are writing in the code, you are reading 16 ints at a time not 16 bits at a time.

Comment: Actually, do you wan't to read a short int at a time or read the bit-fields of a short at a time?

Comment: None of the standard i/o functions read one bit at a time.

Comment: @SudipBhattarai I want to read short int at a time

Comment: To "to read short int at a time", use  `short sh; if (fread(&sh, sizeof sh, 1, myfile) == 1) Success();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `fread(buffer, 1, 1600, myfile);` in order to read a `short`.

This is wrong, as a `short` isn't necessarily 1 byte. Use `sizeof(short)` instead and declare you array as a `short` array.

Comment: @let_the_coding_begin Also, although you don't have to, you may use the `%hd` format in order to print a short.

Comment: I changed the buffer into a short buffer and 1 to the sizeof(short) now i get 20 something This is a shot: 0\n and then numbers like -12288, 25067, and 32767

Answer (score 0):

The code sample you've shown doesn't even use the short keyword.   int and short are not (necessarily) the same size type.

Anyway, the usage of fread() for reading an array of 1600 ints will typically need to be something like

```
fread(buffer, sizeof(int), 1600, myfile);
```

It is also a good idea to check the return value from fread().   If sizeof(int) is 4, and the file contains a total of 400 bytes, fread() will probably return 100, indicating it only managed to successfully read 100 ints.   After all, it is not possible to read 6400 bytes (4*1600 = 6400) in a single fread() statement from a file that contains only 400 bytes.